# SQL update statement:Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have table named dbo.Movies and now i want update 3 rows

This statement works only with one record

```
declare @movietype nvarchar(100) = 'Thriller'
declare @price real = 10
if @price < (select Price from dbo.Movies where MovieType = @movietype)
begin
update mo
   set mo.Price = Price - @price
FROM dbo.Movies as mo
WHERE mo.MovieType = @movietype
end
```

but when i try run this statement to update this 3 rows i got error

> "Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

How i can fix this query to update 3 or more rows?

Comment: I guess that you want to avoid negative price. In that case remove `if` and add `and Price >= @price` to update query in where clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error lies here:

```
if @price < (select Price from dbo.Movies where MovieType = @movietype)
```

You cannot compare a single value (`@price`) to multiple values, you need to make sure the subquery returns only one.

Also, you could just as well rewrite the command like this:

```
UPDATE mo
   SET mo.Price = Price - @price
FROM dbo.Movies as mo
WHERE mo.MovieType = @movietype
  AND mo.Price > @Price
```